# PostgreSQL запрос на сравнение строк

Tags: sql, postgresql

код таблицы доступен до ссылке
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5a4683fa935b2b438500be733ba17f7e

Нужно сравнивать по два дня (27 и 28, 28 и 29) и посчитать  количество профилей, которые есть в предыдущем дне, но не нет в текущем.
К примеру, 27 есть профили 1,2,3 но их нет 28. 
ответ запроса в виде

```
{
 date => 2018-06-28
 count => 3
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дни предыдущий и текущий, это тоже самое, что текущий и следующий, таким образом можно отфильтровать текущие дни по not exists в следующем дне, далее сделать агрегацию с корректировкой даты

Comment: Выглядит как не сложный вопрос. Вы попробуйте сначала самостоятельно. А потом мы подскажем, как исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант, за один проход по таблице

```
select created_at + interval '1 day', count(1)
  from (
    select created_at,
           instagram_profile_id != lead(instagram_profile_id) over(order by instagram_profile_id, created_at)
       or lead(created_at) over(order by instagram_profile_id, created_at) != created_at + interval '1 day' as test
      from instagram_account_followers
  ) x
 where coalesce(test,true)=true
 group by created_at
```

на каждой строке выборки, отсортированной по профилю и дате, заглядываем в следующую по порядку запись и смотрим, что там другой профиль или дата у нее не следующая. Если это так, значит в следующем дне такой записи уже нет. Выбираем такие записи и считаем их, группируя по дню.

[Пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7601cbfcc00e3d1a8c69eb3029a9d765) на вашей выборке

Answer (score 1):

**Возможно нужно такое**

```
select 
  a_created_at_plus_day,
  count(*)
from 
(select 
  a.instagram_profile_id as a_instagram_profile_id,
  a.created_at + interval '1 day' as a_created_at_plus_day,
  b.instagram_profile_id as b_instagram_profile_id,
  b.created_at as b_created_at
from instagram_account_followers as a left outer join
instagram_account_followers as b 
  on 
   a.created_at = b.created_at + interval '-1 day'
   and a.instagram_profile_id = b.instagram_profile_id
where b.instagram_profile_id is null
) as t01
group by a_created_at_plus_day
order by a_created_at_plus_day
```

**Результат**

```
a_created_at_plus_day   count
2018-06-28 00:00:00+01  3
2018-06-29 00:00:00+01  3
2018-06-30 00:00:00+01  2
```

---

А это промежуточный запрос, показывает все колонки, для понимания

```
select 
  a.instagram_profile_id as a_instagram_profile_id,
  a.created_at + interval '1 day' as a_created_at_plus_day,
  b.instagram_profile_id as b_instagram_profile_id,
  b.created_at as b_created_at
from instagram_account_followers as a left outer join
instagram_account_followers as b 
  on 
   a.created_at = b.created_at + interval '-1 day'
   and a.instagram_profile_id = b.instagram_profile_id
```

Результат

```
a_instagram_profile_id  a_created_at_plus_day   b_instagram_profile_id  b_created_at
1   2018-06-28 00:00:00+01  null    null
2   2018-06-28 00:00:00+01  null    null
3   2018-06-28 00:00:00+01  null    null
4   2018-06-28 00:00:00+01  4   2018-06-28 00:00:00+01
5   2018-06-28 00:00:00+01  5   2018-06-28 00:00:00+01
4   2018-06-29 00:00:00+01  null    null
5   2018-06-29 00:00:00+01  null    null
6   2018-06-29 00:00:00+01  null    null
7   2018-06-29 00:00:00+01  7   2018-06-29 00:00:00+01
8   2018-06-29 00:00:00+01  8   2018-06-29 00:00:00+01
```